# How To Handle Exceptions From an "Opaque" Iterator

Tags: python, pandas

What is the best way to handle exceptions from an "opaque" iterator? Specifically, I am using Pandas `read_csv` with the `chunksize` option (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to read large files. I have some corrupt CSV files that, for the sake of this question, are too big/numerous to fix, and I don't need *every line*, besides. I'm happy to read as far as I can before the error crops up, and then just give up on that file and/or skip over the problematic chunk/line. Here's the specific error I'm getting (with non-pandas precursor stuff omitted):

```
  File "/home/hadoop/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1107, in __next__
    return self.get_chunk()
  File "/home/hadoop/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1167, in get_chunk
    return self.read(nrows=size)
  File "/home/hadoop/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1133, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/home/hadoop/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2037, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 860, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 887, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 929, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 916, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2071, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at row 81306332
```

I've already set `error_bad_lines=False` in `read_csv`, so that's not the solution. I think I could set `engine='python'` ([as in this post](https://www.shanelynn.ie/pandas-csv-error-error-tokenizing-data-c-error-eof-inside-string-starting-at-line/)) but if I can keep the speed of C, that's preferable (and again, I'm fine losing some data as long as I don't get errors). I tried something like this in the `for` loop:

```
import pandas.errors

def myiter():
    for i in range(2):
        if i == 0:
            yield i
        else:
            raise pandas.errors.ParserError

my = myiter()
for this in my:
    try:
        print(this)
    except:
        continue
```

but it doesn't work because the iterator, not the `yield`-ed item, raises the error:

```
0

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-5ed872953186> in <module>
      1 my = myiter()
----> 2 for this in my:
      3     try:
      4         print(this)
      5     except:

<ipython-input-3-e8331b7081bf> in myiter()
      4             yield i
      5         else:
----> 6             raise pandas.errors.ParserError

ParserError:
```

What is the correct to handle this? How do I handle a loop error like this gracefully and appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work.

```
my = myiter()
while True:
    try:
        print('trying')
        this = next(my)
        print(this)
    except pandas.errors.ParserError:
        print('ParserError')
        continue
    except StopIteration:
        print('break')
        break
```

```
trying
0
trying
ParserError
trying
break
```